Dependency Cycle in Database with Update Approvals
I'm struggling with a dependency cycle in my SQL database schema for a system with update approvals. Here's the situation:
I have tables for documents , transactions, payment_methods, and updated_transactions.
The updated_transactions table stores proposed updates to transactions, referencing both the original transaction and the proposed updated document and payment method IDs.To clarify, users submit updates to transactions, but these updates require admin approval before they are implemented.
here is the design image
The problem is that the foreign key relationships create a cycle:
documents > transactions > updated_transactions
documents >updated_transactions
and in
payments_methods > transactions > updated transactions
payments_methods >updated_transactions
Here's the provided SQL code for reference:
CREATE TABLE `documents`(
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE `transactions`(
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `payment_method_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `docment_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `updated_state` BIGINT NOT NULL
);
CREATE TABLE `payment_methodes`(
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
);
CREATE TABLE `updated_transactions`(
  `id` BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `updated_payment_method_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `updated_docment_id` BIGINT NOT NULL,
  `id_transaction` BIGINT NOT NULL
);

What are some solutions to break this dependency cycle?

To me it looks like the classical versioning problem.
If I understand your concept description right then your transaction entries should all be immutable. If changes have to be applied to an transaction then a new data entity is being created.
Your design looks a bit more complicated than it could be.
How about this:

add a main_transaction_id (BIGINT) column to your transactions TABLE
add a version (INT) column to your transactions TABLE
Migrate data of your TABLE updated_transactions into your transactions table and forget about TABLE updated_transactions

How does the adjusted concept work?
Whenever you semantically create a new transaction, the column main_transaction_id gets the same value as the column id. The version gets the value 1.
Whenever you semantically create a new version of your transaction you let the AUTO_INCREMENT set the value for the id column but you leave the main_transaction_id field untouched as it had been set in the original transaction entry. Don't forget to increase your version value.
E.G.



id
main_transaction_id
version
...




1
1
1
...


2
1
2
...


3
3
1
...


4
1
3
...


5
5
1
...


6
5
2
...



Optional proposal
Add a created_at DATETIME column to transactions table as it will help you document the relevant timestamps of your transations, in case of complaints or maintenance questions.

Thanks for your response and suggestion! I appreciate your help with the dependency cycle issue.
You're correct that my situation shares some similarities with versioning, but there's a key difference here. In classic versioning, changes are tracked historically. However, in my case, I need to handle update approvals before they become the actual state.
To clarify, users submit updates to transactions, but these updates require admin approval before they are implemented. This is why I need to track both the original and proposed states (through updated_transactions)

Perhaps there's another approach within the concept of versioning that could be adapted to my scenario, considering the need for approval workflows?
